# jQuery sometimes loads in the correct order and sometimes it does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have a website that is running the Master Slider Pro wordpress plugin and the iLightBox plugin. I am running a custom script in a custom.js file in wordpress child theme:

```
/* Link JavaScript file */
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery') , false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
```

I am calling the custom file as per the below in my functions.php file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    (function(){
      var groupsArr = [];
      jQuery('[rel^="ilightbox["]').each(function () {
        var group = this.getAttribute("rel");
        jQuery.inArray(group, groupsArr) === -1 && groupsArr.push(group);
      });
      jQuery.each(groupsArr, function (i, groupName) {
        jQuery('[rel="' + groupName + '"]').iLightBox({ /* options */ });
      });
    })();

  });
```

The issue i am having is that sometimes it loads the custom script (i assume in the correct order) and my slider loads and the lightbox displays when i click the image... other times the slider gets stuck in a loading state and shows the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).iLightBox is not a function
```

I believe i am loading the custom.js file after the jQuery file has loaded... what i am assuming is, that the lighbox plugin is sometimes loading after the jQuery and therefore loading after custom.js file which is why it cannot find the ilightbox function ?

Anyway i can prevent this ?

---

**UPDATE:**
Still struggling with this guys. I have been doing some reading and spoke to my theme author (who has integrated the ilightbox function).

My code now looks like the below:

```
/* register script that defines ilightbox (in parent theme) */
wp_register_script( 'ilightbox_script', get_stylesheet_directory . '/includes/class-avada-scripts.php' );

/* Link JavaScript file */
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery', 'ilightbox_script') , false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts', 99 );
```

I believe i have now registered the script that contains the ilightbox function (stored in my parent theme). I then called the custom.js file after jQuery and the registered script has loaded. However it still is not working. I also get the following error from the file i am now trying to register:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Maybe i have misunderstood everything, so i have copied what the theme author has said to me when i asked which fine defines the ilightbox function.. what do you think?

> These scripts are enqueued in class-avada-scripts.php available in
>   following directory
>
> /wp-content/themes/avada/includes
>
> and all JS code is in main.min.js available in following directory
>
> /wp-content/themes/avada/assets/js
>
> However if you enable developer mode from
>
> Wp admin -> appearance -> theme options -> advanced
>
> then you can modify code in avada-lightbox.js and lightbox.js
>   available in same directory.

Comment: How have you enqueued the lightbox plugin? `iLightBox` isn't included in core jQuery...so you need to include the other relevant scripts as well. If you are including it as part of a plugin, find out what name the script has been registered under and add it to your array of *custom.js* dependencies (e.g. `array( 'jquery', 'ilightbox_whatever' )`)

Comment: please see my update on the original message

Answer (score -1):

You need to load the script and add jQuery as a dependency:

```
// Enqueue a script that has both jQuery (automatically registered by WordPress)
// and my-script (registered earlier) as dependencies.
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-careers-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-careers-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'my-script' ) );
```

Linked from WordPress Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Example_of_Automatic_Dependency_Loading